# Is it possible to say 'You tore my world apart'?

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

Is it possible to say 'You tore my world apart' in poem?
Or I should say 'You've tear my world apart'?

Comment: 'You've tear my world apart' is ungrammatical. Maybe you meant 'you've **torn** my world apart'?

Comment: *You've tear* is not English. *You've* (= *You have*) introduces the perfect construction, with the following verb in past participle form: *You've **torn***. You may read far more than you want to know about using the perfect (and far less than will be enough) at [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially §§ [3.1 Grammatical meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32), [3.2 Pragmatic meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32) and [4. When and how should I use the perfect?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13262/32).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And can I say 'You tore my world apart'?

Comment: Yes, "You tore my world apart" and "You've torn my world apart" are both natural, they are just in different tenses.

Comment: The phrase is not only possible, it's been used in several popular songs, including "Someday" http://genius.com/Eddie-gomez-someday-lyrics# and "U Tore My World Apart".

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot say "You've tear...".

The reason why you need to use "You've torn..." is because of verb tenses; in this case the **[present perfect](http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/present_perfect)**.

The present perfect is constructed like this:

> subject + has/have + past participle